# How to find out if part of the string is in quotes?

Tags: regex

So I have this pattern:

```
{% url my_view %}
{% url my_view user_id %}
```

And this is bad, so instead it should be like this:

```
{% url 'my_view' %}
{% url 'my_view' user_id %}
```

So the `'my_view'` part should always be in quotes. All I need to do Is I need to find all the occurrences where `'my_view'` part is not in quotes.

How can I do it?

Comment: is your problem with brackets or quotes?

Comment: quotes, my bad, thanks for the note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lookarounds:

```
(?<={% url )[^'\s]*(?!')
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/zZ9vF5/3)

Comment: ```my_view``` is just my own example, there could be any text.

Comment: If I also want to exclude ```"my_view"``` should I just add ```"``` like this? ```(?<={% url )[^'"\s]*(?!')``` ?

Comment: @Tachi, yes. Also if you want to be even more specific, you should add it in the lookahead too: `(?<={% url )[^'"\s]*(?!['"])`

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the result of following regex :

```
/\{% url (\S+)(.*)%\}/
```

With :

```
/\{% url \'\1\'\2%\}/
```

Or in some regex engines you may need to use `$1` instead of `\1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to match:

```
(?<=\{% url )(\S+)
```

And replace with:

```
'$1'
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aG7jL1/1)

**Edit:** If you already have some `my_view`'s with quotes use the following:

```
(?<=\{% url )([^']\S+[^'])(?=\s)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aG7jL1/3)